# Show records per page drop down along with export button on datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Unable to show records per page drop down after displaying the export buttons.
I want to display both of them on my table. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
        pageLength: 5,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
        responsive: true
    });
    $('.datetext').datepicker({
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
    });
});
```

Records per page drop down displayed if I remove the buttons on the tables, But I want to display both of them. How to display both of them?

Answer (score 7):

This layout is done here:

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
```

So you have several options for this, and I don't know what you wish to do, but try this:

```
dom: 'flit',
```

This will show the selector on the left.
The buttons you are adding are normally added to the right, so you need to set this to the left.

Comment: I want to display both(selector drop down & export buttons) in top of the datatables , if i use flit,then export buttons are not display

Comment: Try : 'Bflit'. I am sorry but I can not test it. I am not home and I am on my laptop and I don't have DataTables on it.

Comment: IF you want the export button in between the dropdown selector and input filter, use instead "lBfrtip"

Comment: @BoCyrill, exactly what i am looking for, above solution worked but export button hide the number of record in my case, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If i'm not wrong you are looking to have both pagelength and export buttons visible together.
As per me, rather than going for a native drop down you can actually get a real nice button click drop down with the below code, in addition to your native export buttons. You just need to pass the 'pageLength' argument for initializing the DT with additional button which would be the placeholder for page length drop down. Example would be.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        // Configure the drop down options.
        lengthMenu: [
            [ 10, 25, 50, -1 ],
            [ '10 rows', '25 rows', '50 rows', 'Show all' ]
        ],
        // Add to buttons the pageLength option.
        buttons: [
            'pageLength','excel','print'
        ]
    });
});
```

Do not forget to include the select js and css. You can find the [here](https://datatables.net/download/release)

Comment: so nice, actually a different interface then the standard selector, but its a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to show dropdown box og record per page and export button both in one table than use instead "lBfrtip".

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            dom: 'lBfrtip',
            buttons: [
                'copyHtml5',
                'excelHtml5',
                'csvHtml5',
                'pdfHtml5'
            ]
        } );
    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want both **Buttons** and **Show list of rows entries** then use this script.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ]
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `Bfrtip` you can use `Blfrtip` added an `L` (small letter) to enable both export buttons and data display records/entries to show.